# Avoiding duplicate scripts in bundles & tree shaking

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, tree-shaking

So I'm just trying to go through the [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) results looking for things that should be on a diet and understand the CLI build process more in depth (CLI v6.1.5, Angular v6.1.8) and improve our instance.

I noticed that on just a general `ng build` when I go look through the vendor bundle I see;

```
var __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__;/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v3.2.1
```

which is unfortunate as it's unminified as the whole jquery.js file at like 260k+, however I also find this in the scripts bundle;

`/*! jQuery v3.2.1 | (c)` which is the minified file version I would expect considering I have it declared explicitly in my scripts array in `angular.json`

So I figured if I moved it over to the `tsconfig.json` as a module path as;

```
"paths": {
        "jquery": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"],
    }
```

Then it should pick up the min version and strip the other from vendor like I've done with others. Which it does, builds fine, I see the size difference, jquery.js is gone from the vendor bundle....but, I remember there's no typeroots on modules this way so when I go to init I get a crap ton of `error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'` errors. Which, I don't really want `import * as $ from 'jquery'` declarations all over if I can avoid it and also I've got a dependent in the same path on the `angular.json` of some jquery-ui library I've not used as;

```
"scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./vendor_scripts/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js",
.....
```

Where if I just omit the jquery.min.js path then I get `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` all over.

So something in this build process I've inherited is out of line and I'm hoping someone can teach me something. How can I avoid the duplicate scripts to put the bundles on a diet, and how can I make sure I get my typings / ambient declarations respected the correct way? Cheers for reading either way!

Comment: PS, I don't honestly find this to be too broad, certainly others have ran into this specific issue however I do heart the SO and the rules so just let me know.